# Fastest 3, unsigned short Max/Min OR Sort for RGB -> HUE calc, graphics specific

Tags: c, rgb, hue

What is the fastest way to find the max, min and max-min from 3 unsigned shorts all stashed in a 6 byte chuck of memory read from a Photoshop, 16 bit/channel RAW file?

It would be efficient to sort 6 bytes of memory into hi, med and low so I would not have 2 function calls for max and min.

I am building a tool to create a HUEstogram from a 36 MPix, 108MB, D800E NEF file developed to a 16 bit/chan .RAW so it has to be as fast as possible. It is just like a HIstogram except that it will have 0-360° on the X axis instead of the usual intensity bins 1-255. Pixel count per bin on the Y.

I have an Intel 2600k with AES and AVX. There has to be a way to use SSE4.2 registers to do this. I already have GCC *POSSIBLE* options of:

```
-O3 -ffast-math -m64 -Ofast -march=corei7-avx
```

I have gcc  4.8.3/64 (Strawberry Perl), vc 10.0 and TCC 0.9.26 32/64, win7/64. I would like to compile it exactly to the metal without any portability considerations. I can specify either IBM_PC or MAC for endian-ness in Photoshop file->save if that can save a needless byte swap.

There are various macro, function call, assembler, SSE2:_mm_mulhi_epu16, etc solutions proposed here and elsewhere, but none are for UNSIGNED shorts which could greatly simplify the solution without a pesky sign bit to deal with. And, none are for ushort[3] -> [Max, Min, Max-Min]

The entire standard calculation (HUE part) from http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html is:

```
float  r, g, b, h, min, max, delta;
min = MIN( r, g, b );
max = MAX( r, g, b );
delta = max - min;
if( r == max )  h = ( g - b ) / delta;      
else if( g == max )  h = 2 + ( b - r ) / delta; 
else  h = 4 + ( r - g ) / delta;    
if(h < 0 )  h += 6;  // Range =[0, 6]
h *= 60;  // Change to 64k/6 to scale to UShort size!

Hue_Bin = int(h_ushort * bin_count / 64k);  // To calc Hue Bin
```

I want a HUE scaled to a 16 bit unsigned short just like a gray value. Then I will scale to ~2000 bins (input parameter) and count the number of point per bin, and graph just like a histogram.

OR, how about unsigned short min_max_del[3];

```
void crunch(unsigned short r, g, b, *min_max_del)  OR
void crunch(rgb, *min_max_del);  // Where RGB is 6 byte blob with 3 UINTS
```

How hard could it be to take 3 ushorts (R, G and B) and copy the largest, smallest, and delta big-small to an array?
There is not much else obvious here to optimize.

I know there is an assembler solution to do this in 2 inches of code!

Comment: I know one that will do it in 1 inch of code - with a 5-pt font.

Answer (score 0):

In its current form, the code you presented does not make sense for integer color components, and especially not for unsigned ones.  You would have serious problems with integer division and with underflow.  For example, consider the case where `r == max`.  Then the expected magnitude of `g - b` must be less than `delta`, therefore the *integer* quotient `( g - b ) / delta` will be `0` if `g > b`, `1` if `g == r`, or some too-large number if `g < b`.  In the end, having 16-bit unsigned color components simplifies the problem in some ways, but makes it trickier in others.

To combat those problems, you must defer division (and modulo) operations until as late as possible, and be sure to order operations to avoid any possibility of underflow.  While doing so, you must take care to avoid *over*flow, too, which requires using a type wider than 16 bits for many intermediate values.

Additionally, be aware that performance is substantially improved by avoiding unpredictable branches, to which end the ternary operator is often superior to `if`/`else`, as it can often be implemented without a branch.

You need to do it something like this:

```
uint16_t r, g, b;
uint32_t h, max, min, delta;

max = (r < g) ? g : r;
min = (r + g) - max;
max = (max < b) ? b : max;
min = (min < b) ? min : b;
delta = max - min;

if( r == max )  h = (6 * delta + g) - b;
else if( g == max )  h = (8 * delta + b) - r;
else  h = (10 * delta + r) - g;

// hue bin computation:
hue_bin = ((uint32_t) (((uint64_t) h * 60 * bin_count) / (delta << 16))) % bin_count;
```

That still contains two branches.  It would be possible to convert those into branchless computations, but it would be messy, and it would require enough additional operations that any gains might be offset.

Comment: John,  I like your fancy max/min progressive approximation. In Perl, it just works. In C, I did have concerns about over/under-flow. For my application, skin tone analysis, red is max 99.99% of the time. Blue is always last except on Pandora.   I am going to do 2 bizarre picture treatments; rgb -> hue -> rgb with sat=val=1.0 and rgb -> hue/16 viewed as grayscale. Calculating the HUE center of mass with bin*count as moment arm while varying the temp/tint is the major experiment.          Thanks 1E9!